# Unable to use Java Double in @FieldAccess DoFn for fetching nullable DOUBLE schema field

Tags: java, apache-beam

I'm attempting to do the following in my DoFn to extract a double value from an existing nullable field in my schema:

`@FieldAccess("field1") Double field1`

However I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element argument type java.lang.Double
> does not work with expected schema field type DOUBLE

On debugging, the issue seems to be in [ConvertHelpers.getConvertPrimitive()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/utils/ConvertHelpers.java#L151). Specifically, [StaticSchemaInference.fieldFromType()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/utils/StaticSchemaInference.java#L73) seems to return FieldType DOUBLE NOT NULL regardless of whether a Double object or a primitive double is specified. This also then seems to cause a mismatch to the schema type which is only DOUBLE (i.e, without the NOT NULL).

I can't seem to figure out another obvious way to obtain a nullable value via @FieldAccess and the examples/tests in the Beam codebase don't seem to cover this scenario either. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nice find! That sounds like it could be a bug in Beam. Start here: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/new/choose :-)